# How protect my app data in sandbox on jailbroken iphone device?

Tags: ios, root, sandbox, jailbreak

My app maybe install on the jailbroken device. The other application with root permission could delete my app data in sandbox although I set the file with NSFilePosixPermissions 0700. And the application can also pass the jailbreak detection. How can prevent the other application deleting the data in the sandbox? Not encryption question.

Comment: With root permissions on Jailbroken device or any Unix OS, user should be able to delete files/folders. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73773

Comment: Thank you! Dear ARC.  Sigh, no method for protecting..

Comment: Use keychain. Although with jailbreak you can dump keychain contents and possibly change any of it, it will at least give some kind of protection. Modifying keychain takes much more effort.

Comment: @creker  Yes, it's a good solution in normal situation. But the application with root permission can also delete the keychain.

Comment: It can delete individual keys but it's not as simple as deleting a file. You can try to delete whole keychain database but I don't think it's gonna do any good to iOS.

Comment: Thank you @creker ,I put my data in keychain database,but the others delete the whole keychain.